# How to specify a type for a function that returns a new class object

Tags: javascript, types, google-closure-compiler

I am using google closure compiler to typecheck my javascript code.  I have a function which creates and then returns a new "class."  That is, a function which returns an object which can have new applied to it and returns an "instance" object of that class.  E.g.,

```
var newclass = createFactory('Car');
var acar = new newclass();
acar.show();     // executes newclass.prototype.show()
newclass.staticmethod();   // executes newclass.staticmethod()
```

The show and staticmethods were created by the `createFactory` method.

I am having trouble defining the type of newclass to the google closure compiler so that it recognizes newclass as a constructor which has a class method `staticmethod` and an instance method `show`.

Any and all help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does `createFactory()` return a function?  Can you show us the code for createFactory?

Comment: createFactory is in an external library, however, something like:  createFactory(name) = { var x =  function() { };  x.name=name; x.prototype.show = function() { ... }; x.staticmethod=function() { ...}; return x; }

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the generated factory has some common base class or interface (I'll use KnownType). This should do the trick:

```
/** @type {function(new:KnownType)} */
var newClass = createFactory();
```

This says that "newClass" is a function to be called using "new" that returns a instance of KnownType, in this case it is declared as not taking any parameters, but you can.

`CreateFactory` can declare this type as its return type, or anywhere you would normally use a type.